# Unable to print the first element of the string

Tags: c++, vector

I am converting a String to an integer and then passing to a vector and then print it but the first element of the string does not get printed.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
       stringstream ss(str);
       vector<int> my;
       char ch;
       int num;
       while(ss.good()){
           string substr;
           getline(ss, substr, ',');
           ss >> num;
           my.push_back(num);
       }
       return my;
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: i am converting a string to integer and then passes to a vector and then print it but the first element of the string is not get printed]

Comment: Think about what `getline(ss, substr, ',');` is doing - particularly at the start of the string.

Comment: Get the substring if the string from starting point to the first appearance of ‘, ‘ using getline() method.

Comment: ... and what's the next part of the string that will be read by `ss >> num`?

Comment: And immediately afterwards, what do you expet `ss >> num;` to do? Does that make sense to you: hey, extract something from a stream into a string, up until the first comma, but completely ignore it and throw it away, instead use the formatted extraction operator ***on the same stream*** now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the `ss >> num` line. We first start with `1,2,3,4,5` in the stream. `getline(ss, substr, '\n')` reads the first number from the stream (`1`) and gets rid of the delimiter `,`. Then `ss >> num` reads the next number (`2`) but keeps the next `,` in the stream because the formatted operator `>>` only reads as many characters that are valid for the type its being read into. So you threw away the `1` that was stored inside `substr` and pushed in `2` to the vector.

So the stream at this point is `,3,4,5` by the second iteration of the loop. `getline` reads an empty string into `substr` (because there's no number before the `,`) and gets rid of the the delimiter `,` and `ss >> num` reads `3`. This repeats until the entire stream is read: `getline` constantly reads an empty string and `ss >> num` reads in the integer.

The solution is to get rid of the `ss >> num` line and convert `substr` to an integer with `std::stoi`. Also, as a matter of correctness you should put the input operation into the condition of the `while` loop. This way the loop is entered after checking if the input operation succeeded.

```
std::string substr;
while (getline(ss, substr, ',')) {
  my.push_back(std::stoi(substr));
}
```